# execvp() function always returns a negative value

Tags: c, system-calls

I am doing a mocked-shell program for practicing C with Linux-command function, `execvp()`. I know that there is error executing the commands being passed in `execvp` whenever the return value is less than 0. I am positive about my `stringTok()` function process sentence array of characters correctly being passed in since I printed their lengths and string values out for double-checking. For the last token of the sentence, which is essentially the argument list being divided into individual tokens, I assigned `'\0'` character to the last character of that token. 

Eventually, each individual token being assigned to `char*cmdargv[MAX_LINE]`in `stringTok()`. `execvp(cmdargv[0], cmdargv)` is how I passed in my command arguments. For example, "ls -al" is the input and `fgets()` function reads in that string into `args[MAX_LINE]`. The child process will run`execvp`, but a negative value returns and error string prints out. This won't even work as I try to manually assign values to cmd and argv as commented in the code. I think I must have passed in the wrong values in `execvp()` or did something wrong.
     Ideally, if I typed in "ls -al", it should do exactly the same as it would in linux shell, listing all files or directories in the current directory (expected output).

**Input:**
osh>ls -al
**Output:**
args:
len 2
content: ls
last elememnt 115
len 3
content: -al
last elememnt 108
last member:(null)
osh>Error:: Bad address
last member:(null)
osh>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80 


int  stringTok(char* sentence, char** tokens) {

    const char* delim = " \r\n"; 
    int count = 0; 

    // make copy of sentence for strtok 
    size_t len = strlen(sentence);
    char *copy = malloc(len+1); 
    if(!copy) return 0; // if copy null, return 0 
    strncpy(copy, sentence, len); 

    copy[len] = '\0'; 

    // Allocate and copy tokens 
    for(char* word = strtok(copy, delim); 
        word; 
        word = strtok(NULL, delim)) 
    {   
        size_t len = strlen(word); 
        tokens[count] = malloc(len+1);
        if(!tokens[count]) break; 
            strncpy(tokens[count], word, len); 
            tokens[count][len] = '\0'; 
            count++; 
    } 
        size_t strlenth = strlen(tokens[count - 1]);
    //if(count > 1) {
    //   tokens[count - 1][strlenth -1] = '\0'; 
    //}
    tokens[count] = NULL; 
    return count;   
}

int main(void) {
    char args[MAX_LINE]; // command to be executed
    char *cmdargv[MAX_LINE]; // command tokens

    int should_run = 1; 

    do {
        printf("osh>");
        fflush(stdout); 
        fgets(args, MAX_LINE, stdin);
        //fflush(stdout); 

        printf("args:<%s>\n", args);

        int count = stringTok(args, cmdargv);
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            printf("len %ld\n", strlen(cmdargv[i]));
            printf("content: %s\n", cmdargv[i]);
            printf("last elememnt %d\n", cmdargv[i][strlen(cmdargv[i]) - 1]);
        }
        cmdargv[count] = NULL;      
            printf("last member:%s", cmdargv[count]);   
        //printf("cmdargv:%s\n", cmdargv[0]);
        //printf("cmdargc:%d\n", cmdargv[0][strlen(cmdargv[0]) - 1]);
        int pid = fork(); 

        char *cmd = "ls";
        char *argv[3];
        argv[0] = "ls";
        argv[1] = "-la";    

        if(pid == 0) {
            execvp(cmd, argv); 
            if(execvp(cmd, argv) < 0) {
              //printf("Error Executing Command\n");
              perror("Error:");
            }
        } else if (pid > 0) { 
             // if '&' {
             // wait(&pid)
             //}    
        } else {
            printf("Fork failed\n");
            exit(1); 
        } 
        printf("\n"); 
    } while(should_run); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the last member of `cmdargv` to `NULL`?

Comment: Surely you can cut this down to a *much* smaller [mcve].  When you edit the question to put that in place of your current code, do also edit your prose to express an actual question for us to answer.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I did not set the last member of `cmdargv` to be NULL, I only set the last character of the last member of `cmdargv` to be '\0'. Are you suggesting me to add `cmdargv[count] = NULL` in stringTok? I don't think that will help. I tried that.

Comment: @NateLee: How else do you think `execvp()` is going to know how many arguments you passed to it? If you read the manual page, you'll see that the list of arguments passed to `execvp()` *must* be terminated by a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are right. I should have done a better job on asking a more concise and specific problem. My problem is basically that execvp() won't run my argument list commands. I think that's the error I am baffling about.

Comment: Note that `execvp()` only returns when it fails.  If it succeeds, a different program is running in place of the current one; the `execvp()` call does not return when it is successful.  Consequently, there's no need to test the return value from `execvp()`; if it returned, it failed.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths  before the `return count` in `stringTok()` I added token[count] = NULL. But the outcome is still "error executing command" or execvp still returns value -1.

Comment: @NateLee, do not ignore the *first* part of my prior comment, about reducing your code to an MCVE.  Or you might even approach it from the other direction, building an MCVE from scratch.  In general, make every reasonable effort to ask questions that are easy for us to answer.  You'll get better answers that way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Are you suggesting getting rid of `if(execvp(cmdargv[0], cmdargv) == -1)` ? How else will I know if my commands run successfully?

Comment: You don't need the `if` — just use `execvp(cmdargv[0], cmdargv);` because this process (presumably the child) will not return after the `execvp()` if the `execvp()` is successful. If `execvp()` returns at all, it failed. The command you specify completely replaces the current process when you use `execvp()` successfully. The parent process will find out about the failure because the exit status will be non-zero. Note that you should print error messages to standard _error_, not standard output. I also observe that you should normally exit — using `exit()` or `_exit()` or similar — on failure.

Comment: `fgets(args, MAX_LINE, stdin);
        fflush(stdout);` is odd.  I'd expect `fflush(stdout); fgets(args, MAX_LINE, stdin);`

Comment: Suggest `const char* delim = " ";` --> `const char* delim = " \r\n";`  Change `printf("args:%s\n", args);` to `printf("args:<%s>\n", args);` to see why.

Comment: @NateLee: You're still making no attempt to find out *why* `execvp()` is failing. It could be unable to find the file, or a permission problem, or you could have hit your process limit, for all we know, and nothing to do with your code. Call `perror()` after the failure to find out why.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think I see what you were suggesting there, getting rid of `if` with `execvp()`. However, it still did not fix the problem that cmdargv still returns a negative value even when I added `cmdargv[count] = NULL` in `stringTok( )` method. No command was executed from the argument list.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths thanks for suggesting using perror(). It tells me 'Bad Address' which is something useful to start with. But then, why would `cmdargv` resulting in bad address since they are not empty?

Comment: @NateLee `fgets(args, MAX_LINE, stdin);` makes a string ending with a `'\n'` in it.  Code passes that `'\n'` in an `argv[]`.  Surely that causes a problem.

Comment: @chux your suggestion of `printf("args:<%s>\n", args);` does brings '>' to the next line, since each line of input string of characters is appended with '\n' character. I took care that in `stringTok()` method I believe. I set the last char of the last member of the `cmdargv` array of strings replace with '\0'.

Comment: This is the code, `tokens[count - 1][strlenth -1] = '\0';` in `stringTok()` that I use to take care the problem of '\0' with `fgets().` Also, `cmdargv` is the array of strings being passed in `evecvp()` not 'args.'

Comment: "I set the last char of the last member of the cmdargv array of strings replace with '\0'." is blind faith.  Code does not know the last character is a `'\n'`.  Loping off a supposed `'\n'` sends a truncated command to `execv()`.  AFAIK, the last token ends with `"\r\n"`, `"\n"` or neither.  In fact the code is exploitable with `args[0] == 0` and then `tokens[count - 1]` is UB.

Comment: @NateLee: Works fine for me if I set the last argument to `NULL`.

Comment: Since you've not shown the command that you're executing, and not printed the various argument strings, etc, it is hard to know what might be going wrong.  There are many ways for `execvp()` to fail.  You can report the system error via `errno` and `strerror()` (or `perror()`, though personally I don't like that) on standard error before you exit.  At some time, you should read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  An MCVE includes the input and the the expected output — you've not shown that clearly in your question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I edited the problem with some modifications I have made and the input and outputs, hoping that clarifies my problem a little better on why `execvp()` does not work in my case.

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger** `gdb` and [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). Study the source code of existing shells (like `sash` or `bash`)

Comment: The 'paragraph' `{ execvp(cmd, argv); if(execvp(cmd, argv) < 0) { perror("Error:"); } }` should be `{ execvp(cmd, argv); perror("failed to execvp():"); exit(1); }` (or `_exit(1);`) unless you want to follow POSIX and use exit statuses to distinguish between different failure modes (see [Exit status for commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_02)).  (And this is why I don't like `perror()`; it is hard to get a good error message such as `failed to execute 'ls': no such file or directory` that includes the name of the command that failed too.)

Comment: @natelee: "Bad Address" means what it says: one of the pointers in the string array pointed into limbo. If your code inthe question is what you are actually running, that is the result of you not NULL-terminating the array. You carefully NULL-terminate the array you split from the entered command, which is what your debugging output prints, but at the last minute you give `execvp` a completely different array which has not been NULL-terminated. As everyone is telling you, NULL termination is not a little insignificant detail. You must do it; if you don't, the `execvp` will fail, and it did.

Comment: @rici, yeah, I slowly realized missing NULL pointer at the end of the tokens array was just the problem after fully read the manual specifically for exec() family functions. Thanks for everyone's response and I finally resolve that issues. It really gets my nerve that I did not see that earlier.

Comment: @nate: i think you should accept the answer by ikkachu that says that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that is working for me.  It is a bit cleaner on memory allocation — you are leaking furiously in the parent shell (both a copy of the command line and a separate copy of each argument).  They're easy to clean up.  This code handles EOF properly, rather than running into an infinite loop.  It prints the command information without crashing.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80

static int stringTok(char *sentence, char **tokens)
{
    const char *delim = " ";
    int count = 0;

    size_t len = strlen(sentence);
    char *copy = malloc(len + 1);
    if (!copy)
        return 0;
    strncpy(copy, sentence, len);

    copy[len] = '\0';

    for (char *word = strtok(copy, delim);
         word;
         word = strtok(NULL, delim))
    {
        size_t len = strlen(word);
        tokens[count] = malloc(len + 1);
        if (!tokens[count])
            break;
        strncpy(tokens[count], word, len);
        tokens[count][len] = '\0';
        count++;
    }
    size_t length = strlen(tokens[count - 1]);
    tokens[count - 1][length - 1] = '\0';
    tokens[count] = 0;
    free(copy);
    return count;
}

int main(void)
{
    char args[MAX_LINE]; // command to be executed
    char *cmdargv[MAX_LINE]; // command tokens

    int should_run = 1;

    do
    {
        printf("osh>");
        fflush(stdout);
        if (fgets(args, MAX_LINE, stdin) == 0)
        {
            putchar('\n');
            break;
        }

        printf("args:%s\n", args);

        int count = stringTok(args, cmdargv);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            printf("len %ld\n", strlen(cmdargv[i]));
            printf("content: %s\n", cmdargv[i]);
            printf("last character %d\n", cmdargv[i][strlen(cmdargv[i]) - 1]);
        }

        int pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; cmdargv[i] != 0; i++)
                fprintf(stderr, "%d: [%s]\n", i, cmdargv[i]);
            execvp(cmdargv[0], cmdargv);
            int errnum = errno;
            fprintf(stderr, "Error executing command %s (%d: %s)\n",
                    cmdargv[0], errnum, strerror(errnum));
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (pid < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; cmdargv[i] != 0; i++)
                free(cmdargv[i]);
            int corpse;
            int status;
            while ((corpse = waitpid(0, &status, 0)) > 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
            printf("\n");
        }
    } while (should_run);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample run

My program was in executable `xv97` (source `xv97.c`):

```
$ make xv97
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition xv97.c -o xv97
$ ./xv97
osh> extraordinary gallantry
args: extraordinary gallantry

len 13
content: extraordinary
last character 121
len 9
content: gallantry
last character 121
0: [extraordinary]
1: [gallantry]
Error executing command extraordinary (2: No such file or directory)
PID 17445 exited with status 0x0100

osh>    ls    -l    .       
args:    ls    -l    .

len 2
content: ls
last character 115
len 2
content: -l
last character 108
len 1
content: .
last character 46
0: [ls]
1: [-l]
2: [.]
total 8488
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff     2223 Feb 14 13:40 README.md
drwxr-xr-x   19 jleffler  staff      646 May 12 10:15 bin
-rwxr-xr-x    1 jleffler  staff     8712 May 16 16:02 classifier
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff      637 May  8 08:21 classifier.c
drwxr-xr-x    3 jleffler  staff      102 May  1 10:23 classifier.dSYM
drwxr-xr-x   10 jleffler  staff      340 May  1 13:35 doc
drwxr-xr-x    7 jleffler  staff      238 Feb 23 15:11 etc
drwxr-xr-x   18 jleffler  staff      612 Apr  4 12:14 inc
-rwxr-xr-x    1 jleffler  staff     8992 May 16 16:02 iq89
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff     2464 May  1 20:43 iq89.c
drwxr-xr-x    3 jleffler  staff      102 Apr 20 11:56 iq89.dSYM
drwxr-xr-x    5 jleffler  staff      170 Feb 14 13:40 lib
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff      390 May  1 13:35 makefile
drwxr-xr-x  168 jleffler  staff     5712 May 12 11:56 src
-rwxr-xr-x    1 jleffler  staff     9540 May 16 16:43 xv97
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff     2432 May 16 16:43 xv97.c
drwxr-xr-x    3 jleffler  staff      102 May 16 15:55 xv97.dSYM
PID 17452 exited with status 0x0000

osh>^D
$
```

(I edited the list of files a bit — that's why the size is way out of kilter with the sizes of the files shown.)

We can discuss why the maximum line is only 80 characters another day.

I was testing on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.5, using GCC 7.1.0 as the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, that it really helps with your code alongside outputs and description for newbies like me. In fact, I tweak the code a bit on my own got rid of the extra `cmdargv[count] = NULL` in main method since I already had `tokens[count] = NULL` in stringTok(). And it turned out working too.  One thing I am confused about is why you had `tokens[count] = 0.` And also, Can you explain what `while ((corpse = waitpid(0, &status, 0)) > 0)` does? I am guessing that tells you why fork() fails to create child process, right?

Answer (score 2):

> The `execv()`, `execvp()`, and `execvpe()` functions provide an array of
>          pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list
>          available to the new program.  The first argument, by convention,
>          should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.
>          The array of pointers *must* be terminated by a null pointer

Since arrays are passed just as pointers in C, and there's no hidden way for the called function to know the length of the array, it has to be explicitly given. Either in separate argument (say, the `size` argument to `fgets()`), or with the array ending in a known value, like `NULL` (as here with `execv*`). Your code does not set the final argument to `NULL`, which will probably lead to `execlp` returning with a Bad Address error or similar since the uninitialized values following the ones you set will be taken as pointers and are likely to point to invalid memory addresses.

Fixing that issue makes the `exec` work for me, here.

Also, you should use something like `perror()` instead of a constant error message to get some information about *what* error happened. If the `exec` fails, the child process will continue running, so terminate it with `_exit()`.

Comment: What you say is true, and what you recommend is good, but I'm not quite following what you claim is the connection to the question.

Comment: I did try to add a line `token[count] = NULL` before `return count` in my `stringTok()` function. Why is execvp() still returning a negative value?

Comment: @ilkkachu After using perror("error"), it returns "osh>Error:: Bad address" and the last member with `printf("last member of cmdargv:%s" cmdargv[count])` does return a null pointer, (null). And the execvp() still returns a negative value.